# Network Usage in windows 10 never going past 1%?

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, obs

So i started making test streams on my youtube channel using Streamlabs OBS.
I turned on performance mode, looked at the stream but it was like 2 fps.
I looked at task manager and my network usage was NEVER going past 1%, and streamlabs's network usage rarely went past 0.1 mbps.
This happens with other things too, and i don't like it since it makes my internet so slow. Internet (if you're wondering): Verizon Fios 5Ghz connection.

Answer (score 0):

The percentage simply shows the relation between the current network usage and the link speed of your network adapter. For example, if your link speed is 1 Gbps and you're transferring data at 10 Mbps, the network usage will be 1%.

When transferring data over the Internet, the percentage is generally not very useful, because the maximum speed is defined by your ISP and, in your case, is likely to be a lot lower than your adapter speed. Furthermore, your Internet speed can also be degraded by a poor Wi-Fi signal, by other users in the same network, etc.

What you should actually be looking at is the actual speed (in bit/s) at which you are sending data (look at the "Send" field in the performance tab of the task manager) and **compare** that to your Internet speed (which you can learn by doing a speed test).

Comment: Okie. My internet speed is always ~175 mbps so let me check that!